# Getting an anomaly score for every datapoint in SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, random-forest, amazon-sagemaker

I'm very new to SageMaker, and I've run into a bit of confusion as to how to achieve the output I am looking for. I am currently attempting to use the built-in RCF algorithm to perform anomaly detection on a list of stock volumes, like this:

```
apple_stock_volumes = [123412, 465125, 237564, 238172]
```

I have created a training job, model, and endpoint, and I'm trying now to invoke the endpoint using boto3. My current code looks like this:

```
apple_stock_volumes = [123412, 465125, 237564, 238172]
def inference():
    client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
    
    body = " ".join(apple_stock_volumes)
    response = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName='apple-volume-endpoint',
        Body=body,
        ContentType='text/csv'
    )
    inference = json.loads(response['Body'].read())
    print(inference)

inference()
```

What I wanted was to get an anomaly score for every datapoint, and then to alert if the anomaly score was a few standard deviations above the mean. However, what I'm actually receiving is just a single anomaly score. The following is my output:

```
{'scores': [{'score': 0.7164874384}]}
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? Is this an average anomaly score? Why can't I seem to get SageMaker to output a list of anomaly scores corresponding to my data? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have already trained the model on a csv of historical volume data for the last year, and I have created an endpoint to hit.

Edit 2: I've accepted @maafk's answer, although the actual answer to my question was provided in one of his comments. The piece I was missing was that each data point must be on a new line in your csv input to the endpoint. Once I substituted `body = " ".join(apple_stock_volumes)` for `body = "\n".join(apple_stock_volumes)`, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you'll want to get the standard deviation from getting the scores from historical stock volumes, and figuring out what your anomaly score is by calculating `3 * standard deviation`

Update your code to do inference on *multiple* records at once

```py
apple_stock_volumes = [123412, 465125, 237564, 238172]
def inference():
    client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
    
    body = "\n".join(apple_stock_volumes). # New line for each record
    response = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName='apple-volume-endpoint',
        Body=body,
        ContentType='text/csv'
    )
    inference = json.loads(response['Body'].read())
    print(inference)

inference()
```

This will return a list of scores

Assuming `apple_stock_volumes_df` has your volumes and the scores (after running inference on each record):

```py
score_mean = apple_stock_volumes_df['score'].mean()
score_std = apple_stock_volumes_df['score'].std()
score_cutoff = score_mean + 3*score_std
```

There is a great example [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/random_cut_forest/random_cut_forest.ipynb) showing this

Comment: Ah, so... am I supposed to run invoke_endpoint for each item in the list I want to detect anomalies on, with "body" set to a separate volume each time? I did train the model on a csv of historical volume figures. I also already have a pre-created endpoint I want to use, so I don't want to be creating a new endpoint in the code. @maafk

Comment: In this case you'd run the historical csv volumes against your endpoint (could also do batch inference) to get the mean score and standard deviation. From these data points you can get a score cutoff value (typically more than 3 standard deviations), and incorporate that in your production code to flag scores greater than the score cutoff value

Comment: So sorry, I have one more question. What do you mean by "run the historical volumes against the endpoint"? Whenever I include volumes in csv format in the body of invoke_endpoint(), I get only a single anomaly score back, as shown in the op. Is that not what's meant by "running against"? I don't really understand how I could get a mean or standard dev from the single score I'm getting back.

Comment: I attempted this using Sagemaker.predictor.Predictor('apple-volume-endpoint').predict(body) as well, and I'm still only getting a single anomaly score. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ahh I understand. Try with `body = "\n".join(apple_stock_volumes)`, which should provide a new line per record

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. That solved it - this exactly the kind of small detail that's easy to miss as a newbie. I really appreciate your kindness in responding!

Comment: Hi @maafk . How can I get a response fron invoke_endpoint using xboost with the score class in binary problem? I getting just the probs in `response[Body]`, but I would like to get the inference with the class and it confidence score (prob). tkx in advance, guys.